# How to create an adaptive button in Figma?

Tags: user-interface, figma

I just want to create a simple button with background color and text inside it, so that the width of the button will adapt to the text inside it.

So lets say I have a button 56px wide with text saying "cancel" in it, but if I change the text to "Please click here to cancel and bla bla bla" - I'd then have to manually resize the button's background to match the new text.

Is there a way to automate this part of the design process?

PS: sorry for the irrelevant tags, but there is no tag "Figma" here. This question is for Figma users only!

Answer (score 1):

Figma has introduced a wonderful tool for this. "Figma Auto Layout"
Check out this on their official blog. https://www.figma.com/blog/announcing-auto-layout/

It does exactly what you've mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic button function doesn't exist yet in Figma.
SketchApp have some plugin that help you doing the job.